# null pointer exception while running doInBackground method 

Tags: android, dropbox

i am trying to upload a file to dropbox, i have a also create a progress bar to check its status but while executing it throws exception .
i created a object of UploadFile class and call the UploadFile function and the argument  which are pass are UploadData.this, mApi,FILE_DIR ,file.

```
public class UploadFile extends AsyncTask<Void, Long, Boolean> {
private DropboxAPI<?> mApi;
private String mPath;
private File mFile;
private long mFileLen;
private UploadRequest mRequest;
private Context mContext;
private final ProgressDialog mDialog;
private String mErrorMsg;
public UploadFile(Context context, DropboxAPI<?> api, String dropboxPath,
        File file) 
{
    mContext = context.getApplicationContext();
    mFileLen = file.length();
    mApi = api;
    mPath = dropboxPath;
    mFile = file;

    mDialog = new ProgressDialog(context);
    mDialog.setMax(100);
    mDialog.setMessage("Uploading " + file.getName());
    mDialog.setProgressStyle(ProgressDialog.STYLE_HORIZONTAL);
    mDialog.setProgress(0);
    mDialog.setButton("Cancel", new OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
            // This will cancel the putFile operation
            mRequest.abort();
        }
    });
    mDialog.show();
}

@Override
protected Boolean doInBackground(Void... params) {
    try {
        FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(mFile);
        String path = mPath + mFile.getName();
        mRequest = mApi.putFileOverwriteRequest(path, fis, mFile.length(),
                new ProgressListener() {
            @Override
            public long progressInterval() {
                return 500;
            }
            public void onProgress(long bytes, long total) {
                publishProgress(bytes);
            }
        });

        if (mRequest != null) {
            mRequest.upload();
            return true;
        }

    } catch (DropboxUnlinkedException e) {
        mErrorMsg = "This app wasn't authenticated properly.";
    } catch (DropboxFileSizeException e) {
        mErrorMsg = "This file is too big to upload";
    } catch (DropboxPartialFileException e) {
        mErrorMsg = "Upload canceled";
    } catch (DropboxServerException e) {
        if (e.error == DropboxServerException._401_UNAUTHORIZED) {
        } else if (e.error == DropboxServerException._403_FORBIDDEN) {
        } else if (e.error == DropboxServerException._404_NOT_FOUND) {

        } else if (e.error == DropboxServerException._507_INSUFFICIENT_STORAGE) {
            // user is over quota
        } else {
            // Something else
        }
        // This gets the Dropbox error, translated into the user's language
        mErrorMsg = e.body.userError;
        if (mErrorMsg == null) {
            mErrorMsg = e.body.error;
        }
    } catch (DropboxIOException e) {

        mErrorMsg = "Network error.  Try again.";
    } catch (DropboxParseException e) {
        mErrorMsg = "Dropbox error.  Try again.";
    } catch (DropboxException e) {
        mErrorMsg = "Unknown error.  Try again.";
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
    }
    return false;
}

@Override
protected void onProgressUpdate(Long... progress) {
    int percent = (int)(100.0*(double)progress[0]/mFileLen + 0.5);
    mDialog.setProgress(percent);
}

@Override
protected void onPostExecute(Boolean result) {
    mDialog.dismiss();
    if (result) {
        showToast("Image successfully uploaded");
    } else {
        showToast(mErrorMsg);
    }
}

private void showToast(String msg) {
    Toast error = Toast.makeText(mContext, msg, Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
    error.show();
}
}
```

here is the log (i am new to this and i don't understand the log properly)

```
06-30 06:18:34.400: W/dalvikvm(422): threadid=7: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x4001d800)
06-30 06:18:34.410: E/AndroidRuntime(422): FATAL EXCEPTION: AsyncTask #1
06-30 06:18:34.410: E/AndroidRuntime(422): java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occured while executing doInBackground()
06-30 06:18:34.410: E/AndroidRuntime(422):  at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:200)
06-30 06:18:34.410: E/AndroidRuntime(422):  at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerSetException(FutureTask.java:273)
06-30 06:18:34.410: E/AndroidRuntime(422):  at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:124)
06-30 06:18:34.410: E/AndroidRuntime(422):  at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:307)
06-30 06:18:34.410: E/AndroidRuntime(422):  at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:137)
06-30 06:18:34.410: E/AndroidRuntime(422):  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1068)
06-30 06:18:34.410: E/AndroidRuntime(422):  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:561)
06-30 06:18:34.410: E/AndroidRuntime(422):  at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1096)
06-30 06:18:34.410: E/AndroidRuntime(422): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
06-30 06:18:34.410: E/AndroidRuntime(422):  at com.sachin.UploadFile.doInBackground(UploadFile.java:59)
06-30 06:18:34.410: E/AndroidRuntime(422):  at com.sachin.UploadFile.doInBackground(UploadFile.java:1)
06-30 06:18:34.410: E/AndroidRuntime(422):  at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:185)
06-30 06:18:34.410: E/AndroidRuntime(422):  at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:305)
```

Comment: What type of exception are you getting? On which line?

Comment: mRequest = mApi.putFileOverwriteRequest(path, fis, mFile.length(), new ProgressListener() {
                @Override
                public long progressInterval() {
                    return 500;
                }
                public void onProgress(long bytes, long total) {
                    publishProgress(bytes);
                }
            });

Comment: Why don't you try initializing mRequest outside doInBackground. I don't know what the function does but if it is somehow related to UI, it might be giving the RunTimeException.

Comment: i have initialized mRequest outside only its UploadRequest and i have initialize that at top

Comment: 06-30 06:18:34.410: E/AndroidRuntime(422): java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occured while executing doInBackground()

Comment: There should probably be another explanation of the error under that. Do you have a chance to post all of the logcat?

Comment: java has *methods*, not functions.

Comment: what line is "line 59" in your `doInBackground` method? this is where the `NullPointerException` occurs according to the logcat: `at com.sachin.UploadFile.doInBackground(UploadFile.java:59)` So which line is line 59?

Comment: mRequest = mApi.putFileOverwriteRequest(path, fis, mFile.length(), new ProgressListener() { @Override public long progressInterval() { return 500; } public void onProgress(long bytes, long total) { publishProgress(bytes); } });

Comment: I am guessing you fail to initialize mRequest properly. That's why its set to null. I never used DropBox API so I can only guess that.

Comment: when you get a mysterious error, the first thing you should always, always, ***always*** do is look at the logcat and find the line number that caused the error. doing so is actually really simple, as most of the time all you need to do is find the *top* line in the logcat that contains your package name. hope that makes sense

Comment: What I would recommend is: Put a break point on that line and debug your application. When it stops there, check all the variable values you are using on that line. If one of them is null, there is your error.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you properly initialize

```
UploadRequest mApi;
```

as not doing so will cause a `NullPointerException` when the `onClick` method is called.

Comment: i have initialize UploadRequest mRequest; properly still i don't understand the problem.

Comment: oops, sorry I meant `mApi`. Do you properly initialize the `api` argument that is passed into the `UploadFile()` constructor?

Comment: if possible i can send u the pic of the variable and u can help me out . i have use the break point inline 59 and noted the variable, and i am new to programming so can u help me out.

Answer (score 0):

Put a break point on the line where you have the exception and debug your application. When it stops there, check all the variable values you are using on that line. If one or more is null, there is your error. Those are the variables that you forget to initialize before using in that method.

Comment: if possible i can send u the pic of the variable and u can help me out . i have use the break point inline 59 and noted the variable, and i am new to programming so can u help me out.

Comment: @sachin, are you using Eclipse? If yes, make sure you are doing as said here: http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/os-ecbug/. If you still have the problem, post me the values of all these variables: mApi, path, fis, mFile.