# An error occured while executing doInBackground() on first line of Activity

Tags: android, android-asynctask, nullpointerexception

I'm getting crash reports only occasionally from users devices. It is happening on AysncTask doInBackground(), but what's strange to me about is that the line were it is happening is only on line 1 of the activity (ActivityY). What could be null there? How do I debug this? I don't know if this is relevant but it seems to only happen on AsyncTask$2.

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occured while executing doInBackground()
   at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:300)
   at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.finishCompletion(FutureTask.java:355)
   at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:222)
   at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:242)
   at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:231)
   at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
   at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
   at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:841)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
   at com.X.X.ActivityY$ItemRetrieve.doInBackground(ActivityY.java:1)
   at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:288)
   at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
   at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:231)
   at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
   at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
   at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:841)
```

Activity Y is pretty big so can't post all of it, but here is the basic outline of the AsyncTask class ItemRetrieve:

```
class ItemRetrieve extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Boolean> { 
  @Override
  protected Boolean doInBackground(Void...v) {
    //Internal Logic
    if(does_not_work){
        return false;
    }
    //more code...
    return true;
  }

  @Override         
  protected void onPostExecute(Boolean result) {
    if(result = true){
        //more code....
    }
    else {
        //do nothing
    }
  }      
}
```

The first line of ActivityY is just the package declaration.

Comment: can you show async task logic...

Comment: ActivityY source code would be great

Comment: its a big activity so i couldn't add everything but i added the basic logic of the async task

Comment: They exact code in the `doInBackground()` is going to be needed before anyone can suggest a fix.  Plus, you'll also need to provide the supporting code from the `Activity`.  Is your `doInBackground()` using something not provided to it as an argument?  My guess is yes since it is setup to take `Void` arguments.  If so, then whatever member fields/data your `doInBackground()` is accessing is `null` when it is running.

Comment: well my question is if its crashing on a different line (in doInBackground()) why is it reporting the line with null pointer as line 1 in the activity? there are many examples out there like that where there is a null pointer on another line and then further back it mentions line 1...see for example http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11270531/null-pointer-exception-while-running-doinbackground-method but i couldn't find other examples where the crash report only points to the first line

Comment: @LarrySchiefer i am facing same issue can help me out, hopefully waiting for reply

Comment: @SunishthaSingh there's not enough in this post to make sense of what is going on.  If you've got a specific issue and have posted it to SO, add a link and I'll be happy to take a quick look.

Comment: yeah sure i'll be uploading question with deatils, then i will edit link. I need help for resolving that warnings

Answer (score 0):

if you are updating your UI, sending interface or showing some toast or any in doinbackground(), it will show this error, please use them in postexecuted()..

Doinbackground is only for process some code not for UI